# Is adobe cs6's plugin available in creative cloud?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have to upgrade a **`adobe illustrator plugin`** from cs4 to the latest `adobe creative cloud`.

I have search through the net but I cannot find any sdk for creative cloud's plugin development.

So I'm wondering can we use `CS6's plugin sdk` to build `creative cloud's plugin`?

**Edit:**
It seems that adobe haven't release any details about plugins in CC. Anyone knows further information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, unless you were part of a pre-release program, the SDK has always been released on the same day as the application. Two weeks ago, it was announced that CC would ship on June 17, so the SDK should be available at that time. In the meantime, you might as well use the CS6 SDK to update the plug-in as needed. Then, there should be fewer changes to make when you get the CC SDK. For information on how to join the Adobe Developer program and possibly be eligible to participate in a pre-release program visit http://www.adobe.com/devnet.html.